# How to force flush old cache in visitor browser

Tags: wordpress, caching, browser-cache

recetnly i changed cache plugin from WP fastest cache to WP Rocket. I had to move some inline JS codes to file. The issue is some repeat visitors can have old JS file in browser cache. Is there some way, how to force delete it, when they visit site?

Answer (score 1):

My Idea would be to still put a reference to the old files like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/myOldFile.js?2"></script>
```

I haven't tested wether it works with deleted files. But it works with changed files. So my assumption is, that it also could work with a deleted one.

The index 2 after the question mark in the link will force the brower to reload the file and remove the old one from cache. You can change to index whenever a file was changed.

I've tested it on many browsers and WebView Objects (WKWebView and Android WebView).